# Detect whether or not Certbot made changes when called from Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have certbot executing successfully via Ansible with:

```
- name: Create and Install Cert Using Nginx Plugin
  command: "certbot --nginx {% for host in certbot_domains %}  -d {{ host }} {% endfor %} -m {{ certbot_email }} --agree-tos --noninteractive --redirect"
  become: true
  become_user: root
```

However, even when nothing changes it gets marked as "changed" by Ansible.

I came across this [Issue Comment](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/4090#issuecomment-282605558) suggesting the way around it is to use use a Post Hook to touch a file (`--post-hook "touch change_occured"`) but I'm not sure what to do next.

Do I register the result and use a `changed_when:` to detect that file? If so, what's the syntax? All the file existence checks I can find seem to be the whole task, not going in a `changed_when:` statement.

Is there a better way to detect if certbot actually made any changes?

Comment: Does the command include text in its output that lets you know a change occurred, or it's just silent? And, either way, from ansible's point of view, I believe you'd want `--post-hook "echo ///CHANGED///"`, then `register: certbot` and `changed_when: '"///CHANGED" in certbot.stdout'` type deal

Comment: I can think of good reasons to use Ansible for this, but I just want to make sure you have weighed these with the simplicity and reliability of `cron` for updating your certs. Or you could use both - `cron` to update and Ansible to verify that the cert is less than X days old.

Comment: @mdaniel I figured out something similar soon after posting... If the post hook is executed Ansible announces "Running post-hook command: ....". So I used `--post-hook "echo > /dev/null 2>&1` and `changed_when: "'Running post-hook command' in certbot_output.stdout"`. If you want to post it as an answer I'll happily accept it

Comment: Good question @bitinerant! This is a small part of a much larger Ansible playbook (which also adds a cron task for renewing certs). The main goal is to let me run the playbook again for other changes without certbot saying something changed when it didn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From ansible's point of view, I believe you'd want `--post-hook "/bin/true"`, then `register: certbot_output` and `changed_when: '"Running post-hook command' in certbot_output.stdout`:

```yaml
- name: Create and Install Cert Using Nginx Plugin
  command: >-
     certbot --nginx {% for host in certbot_domains %}  -d {{ host }} {% endfor %}
     -m {{ certbot_email }}
     --agree-tos --noninteractive --redirect
     --post-hook "/bin/true"
  register: certbot_output
  changed_when: "'Running post-hook command' in certbot_output.stdout"
  become: true
  become_user: root
```

Using the string detection in the process output is easier from ansible's point of view because detecting the timestamp of any written-to file would require a 2nd `stat:` task which makes "did the certbot command change" an awkward question to answer